# Windows server Task Scheduler, close after?

Tags: windows-server-2003

I have a scheduled task on my server which runs a PHP script every minute. In the 'Run' part of the scheduled task I have the following:

```
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "http://www.example.co.uk/script.php"
```

So when it runs it opens Internet Explorer and browses to that URL.

Is it possible to get it to close Internet Explorer after running the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may install [PHP](http://php.net/downloads.php) on you windows server, put php.exe in to the global PATH variable, and just start your php-script file from "Task Manager" with:

```
C:\PHP\bin\php.exe "http://www.example.co.uk/script.php"
```

I think there will no windows in this case ;)

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing, but When it runs php.exe it says it cannot load modules. What does that mean?